# How to reassign keyboard shortcut for Plasma Search

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, launcher

In KDE I set `Alt-Space` as the shortcut for switching input languages, but this shortcut also invokes Plasma Search. I couldn't find how to control keyboard shortcuts for Plasma Search (looked in the Global Shortcuts menu and the like).

Can someone please let me know how to reassign this keyboard shortcut for Plasma Search?

Comment: Have you looked for "Run Command" in Global Shortcuts? There, you can change the shortcut for "Run Command" (which launches krunner) from `Alt+Space` to whatever you like.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In later versions is under Shorcuts - Krunner

[image]

Most shortcuts can be used I guess, but for Super/Meta key [other settings may be needed](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=151477#p396023). (I have not tested them, and thus could not use Meta for Krunner; and I don't recommend them either).

---

I would suggest to keep Meta (single) key for the default search/launch with the Applications_Menu/Dashboard (by keeping/setting shortcut to Alt-F1), Alt-Space for Krunner search/launch and Meta-Space for switching keyboard layouts under *Alternative shortcut*, because this displays them on the screen while switching; something you don't get with the shortcut set under *Main*. (In fact, for any shortcut for switching layouts, I suggest to set it under *Alternative shortcut*, instead of *Main*.)

[image]

[image]